# how to wait till a string element gets its value and then write it in java

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, for-loop

I'm  tyring to write a script in selenium java where I have `for` loop, in which I'm printing the values of *count*, My problem is that it prints the value of 1st *count* in second statement ,second *count* to third & so on..
simply it left first `sysout` statement blank and the prints first *count* value to second `sysout` statements and so on..It works when I put `Thread.sleep()` block before printing it , but I need a solution that check count has some valid count & then only print the statement, because some times  'count' take 2+minutes to retrieve value, and Thread only wait for 10 seconds and also not a feasible solution to apply Thread.sleep()
here is my code block

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        MS_items.get(i).click();
        String MS_Elem = MS_items.get(i).getAttribute("value");
        WebElement getCount = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-info form-control margin-bottom'][.='Get Count']")));
        getCount.click();
        String count = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='alert alert-count']/p/b"))).getText();
        //Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("MS Name: " + MS_Elem + " count : "+ count);
        if(count!= "0"){
            MS_items.get(i).click();
        }

        if (count == "0") {
            Assert.assertEquals(false, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have  MS_items.get(i).click(); 2 times for count != 0?

Comment: @VitaliyMoskalyuk it is to click on next element, if value is not zero

Comment: it is to deselect first selected checkbox and then click on next element